# GWT - Can't Finding entry point classes

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jakarta-ee, compiler-errors

I have recently started developing another GWT module. So I created a package with all my new classes and one specific class that implements a new entrypoint. I modified  in my gwt.xml to my new entrypoint. When I compile, I get the following error:

```
 GWT Compiling client-side code.
WARNING: 'com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Use 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' instead.
(To disable this warning, pass -Dgwt.nowarn.legacy.tools as a JVM arg.)
Compiling module com.test.gwt
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.test.ajax.input.createEntryPoint'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
```

This isnt a capital letter mistake, both path in gwt.xml and my actual package are written the same... Any clues?

Comment: The GWT compiler may not be pointing at any of your code.  Are you using GWT through Eclipse or some other manner?  Do you know why you're getting the deprecated warning?  How do you actually invoke the compiler.

Comment: I am using netbeans with the plugin gwt4nb. The deprecated warning has always been there, even when my code could compile and work properly. Im not sure by what you mean "invoke", but to initiate the compile process I right click on my project, and hit build. Tried cleaning, didnt change anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. make sure your code is in 'client' subpackage
2. make sure your .gwt.xml file is in client's parent package

for example change your directory/package structure to this:

```
com/test/ajax/input/client/createEntryPoint.java
com/test/ajax/input/Module.gwt.xml
```

Your Module.gwt.xml should contain the follownig line:

```
<entry-point class="com.test.ajax.input.client.createEntryPoint"/>
```

more: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html

Comment: My code wasnt in the subpackage client, this is what was the problem. I just refractored all my new code in client/input instead.